# Misunderstanding of conics.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Is a conic a hypersurface defined by a degree 2 polynomial?

A conic is an intersection of a cone and a plane. So as a zero set, it is defined by a degree 2 polynomial and a linear equation. Now suppose this definition of a conic is equivalent to being a hypersurface defined by a degree 2 polynomial. Then it follows that the radical of the ideal say $(X^2 + Y^2 - Z^2, aX + bY + cZ)$ and the radical of our principal ideal generated by a degree 2 polynomial are equal. That is, the radical of our principal ideal contains a linear polynomial so is in fact a principal ideal generated by a linear polynomial...which is in fact a plane. A conic is definitely not a plane. What is my misunderstanding here?

Comment: Ok so when we speak of a conic in say $k^n$ defined by a degree 2 polynomial, this is in fact the intersection of a cone and plane in $k^{n + 1}$?

Comment: A quadric hypersurface is defined by a degree 2 polynomial (homogeneous if you're in projective space). You seem to be thinking only of a conic *curve*, which must lie in a plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah okay that makes a lot more sense. So is "conic" in the context of algebraic geometry usually referring to a quadric hypersurface?

Comment: No, it usually is used just for curves. In higher dimensions, we use the word quadric or hyperquadric.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.